# Hiding .aspx from url in ASP.NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would require to hide .aspx extension and query sting values from complete url. I have tried many solution online but didn't succeeded.

After long search I have found one sample code article (linked below):
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-hide-remove-ASPX-extension-in-URL-in-ASPNet.aspx

Now, in this article it's given at starting that it would build using **Framework 3.5 & Service Pack 1**.

Even I have checked the Visual Studio 2008 I have installed on my machine is Framework 3.5 & SP1. Therefore I have tried this application.

But there are some issues while I have tried this solution.

ie:

1. As we have to import **Routing** package (System.Web.Routing), I have imported it, but it didn't recognized. Then I have manually referenced the Routing package from **.NET Libararies**.
2. After that it didn't recognizing the method of (**routes.MapPageRoute**).
3. This method is being used to manually set the alias for url, but it shows me **Blue Underline** under this method and on running it shows me the message as (**MapPageRoute is not a member of System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection**).

so, please guide me according to this solution.

Comment: I guess you need to look at iframe

Comment: Kindly dont use the word **SIR**

Comment: I don't think RouteCollection.MapPageRoute is available in ASP.NET 3.5 only 4.0 and 4.5, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it's available only on .net framework 4.0 & 4.5